# Not change the colour of status bar to colorPrimary

Tags: android, android-statusbar

Can I prevent the colour of the status bar becoming `colorPrimary`? I mean, I do not want to change the status bar colour, and leave it as it is (system default). I have searched Google for this, and the answer was hiding the status bar. But I do not want to hide it.

I also do not want to change the primary colour to that of the default colour of the status bar. I need the primary colour as it is for other things. I just do not want it to be applied to the status bar.

I know that was the default behaviour before Lollipop. Is this still possible after Lollipop?

Comment: simply set status bar color to black as it was on previous versions of android

Comment: you need to set it black which is default for api<19. set black for api>=19

Comment: Did you tried removing the `colorPrimaryDark` attribute from the theme (styles.xml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application theme, set status bar color as below:

```
<item name="statusBarColor">"YOUR_COLOUR_CODE"</item>
```

Comment: So, I must change it to *some* colour, and cannot leave it as it (not changing the colour at all)? If that is the only way, I will accept this as the solution.

Comment: Yes, ideally for default use Black.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#000000</item>
 </style>
```